# Why does S3 file upload not trigger event to SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I want a certain HTTPS service to be called every time a file has been uploaded to an S3 bucket.

I have created the S3 bucket and a SNS topic with a verified subscription with the HTTPS service as an endpoint.
I can publish a message on the SNS topic via the AWS UI, and see that the HTTPS service is called as expected.
On the S3 bucket I created an Event, which should link the bucket and the topic. On my first attempt I got an error because the bucket was not allowed to write to the topic, so c.f. the documentation, I changed the topic access policy to:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:TOPIC_ID:OrderUpdates",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "ACCOUNT_ID"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

where TOPIC_ID is the topic owner id which can be seen when the topic is shown in the AWS UI, and the ACCOUNT_ID is the account id shown under account settings in the AWS UI.
This change in the topic access policy allowed me to create the event on the bucket:
[image]

When I call the API method getBucketNotificationConfiguration I get:

```
{
    "TopicConfigurations": [
        {
            "Id": "OrderFulfilled",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:TOPIC_ID:OrderUpdates",
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "QueueConfigurations": [],
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": []
}
```

But the HTTPS service is not called. What am I missing in this setup, that will trigger the HTTPS service to be called by the SNS topic subscription every time a file is uploaded to the S3 bucket?

Thanks,
-Louise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce this situation, I did the following:

- Created an **Amazon SNS topic** and **subscribed** my phone via SMS (a good way to debug subscriptions!)
- Created an **Amazon S3 bucket** with an **Event** pointing to the Amazon SNS topic

I received this error message:

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Permissions on the destination topic do not allow S3 to publish notifications from this bucket.

- I then added the policy you show above (adjusted for my account and SNS ARN)
- This allowed the Event to successfully save

**Testing**

- I then tested the event by **uploading a file** to the S3 bucket.
- I **received an SMS** very quickly

So, it would appear that your configuration should successfully enable a message to be sent via Amazon SNS. This suggests that the problem lies with the **HTTPS subscription**, either from sending it from SNS or receiving it in the application.

I recommend that you add an Email or SMS subscription to verify whether Amazon SNS is receiving the topic and forwarding it to subscribers. If this works successfully, then you will need to debug the receipt of the message in the HTTPS application.

Comment: Hi John. Thank you for your answer. I have now added an additional email subscription, and verified that it is triggered by publishing a message via the UI on the topic. But when I upload a new file, I do not receive an email either. Do you upload via the UI? Do you know about any other settings that must be enabled? I am new to AWS so maybe I blocked the bucket from publishing messages in a setting by mistake, as there are quite a few settings.

Comment: I did exactly as described above, changing only the Account ID and SNS ARN in the policy. I'm not familiar with anything that could stop it from working. I suggest you "bring a friend" as you configure it, to see whether any obvious steps are missed. (I uploaded via the S3 management console.)

Comment: Ok I tried creating the topic and the bucket from scratch using the default settings, and now it works - thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Having the same issue S3 upload event does not trigger sns message even though our sns access policy is correctly set. Turns out we can NOT use the `Enable encryption` option, since S3 events are triggered via CloudWatch Alarms which do not work with SNS *encrypted* topics as of now.

Switch back to *Disable encryption* option, everything works again.

Comment: S3 events to SNS did not work. **I turned off encryption**, boom it worked! Nice. I would have not thought of that. Nasty.

Comment: If your topic needs to be encrypted, you can use a customer managed key for encryption and grant access to the CloudWatch service according to AWS support: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-receive-sns-for-alarm-trigger/

Comment: Terrible that their standard docs for setting up a typical “fan out” architecture for s3 triggered events don’t mention this incompatibility with the baked in sns encryption mechanism. Have raised a request for them to make the docs clearer.

Answer (score -1):

You must add TopicConfiguration

Read more about [enable event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#how-to-enable-disable-notification-intro)

Comment: Yes that seems to be if I want to set it up programmatically, but I should be able to do it via the UI as well right - as the setup from the event screenshot I added?

Comment: Ok I just confirmed that creating the event via the UI is the same as creating a TopicConfiguration via the API.
When I call getBucketNotificationConfiguration I get:
{
 "TopicConfigurations": [
  {
   "Id": "OrderFulfilled",
   "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:ACCOUNT_ID:OrderUpdates",
   "Events": [
    "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "QueueConfigurations": [],
 "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": []
}